# Android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested

Tags: android

When I try to upload an image it gives me error mission below. Before compile SDK 26 its working fine

> I am using this library for uploading an image: compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1' what should I do???

getPath() method:

```
//method to get the file path from uri
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

uploadMultiPart() method:

```
public  void uploadMultipart() {

            String path = getPath(filePath);

            //Uploading code
            try {
                String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                //Creating a multi part request
                new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, AppConfig.RECEIPT_URL)
                        .addFileToUpload(path, "image") //Adding file
                        .addParameter("emp_id", emp_id) //Adding text parameter to the request

                        .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                        .setMaxRetries(7)
                        .startUpload(); //Starting the upload
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Upload Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

}
```

Here is my error code:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.indore.ddagro, PID: 6609
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
    at com.indore.ddagro.activity.RecepitActivity.getPath(RecepitActivity.java:230)
    at com.indore.ddagro.activity.RecepitActivity.uploadMultipart(RecepitActivity.java:153)
    at com.indore.ddagro.activity.RecepitActivity.onClick(RecepitActivity.java:276)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Force finishing activity com.indore.ddagro/.activity.RecepitActivity
Showing crash dialog for package com.indore.ddagro u0
```

Comment: I think your cursor is empty, look for why is it empty

Comment: `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` the cursor returned no rows (**size of 0**).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that your search in the database is returning 0 rows in the query method.

**First case:** It probably has nothing in the table, since you are passing `null` in all the parameters of the query method.

**Second case:** The other query is also not finding anything in the specific table with the parameters passed in the query method. Or the table is also empty.

**Third case:** It may be something in your content provider, but I'm not really sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are passing `filepath` null to `getPath()` so check it with `if condition` like below

```
 String path = "";

    if (!Uri.EMPTY.equals(filePath)) {

        path = getPath(filePath);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image not selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```